# Как понизить версию SDK в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Собственно задача, есть Android Studio 2.2.3.
При создании проекта указывается только минимальная версия SDk, а версия Compile SDK не указывается и берется максимально возможная. Все бы нечего, но потом понизить версию SDK через Project Structure не удается, из за того что, (как я понимаю) куча ресурсов которые есть в последней SDK отсутсвует в предыдущих SDK. Пример ошибок:

```
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that  matches the given name  'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
```

Собственно вот такая проблема.

PS
Зачем это нужно. Беру я руководство  какое нибудь по программированию - пытаюсь взять пример оттуда и выясняется что методы которые там используются уже deprecated.

UPDATE
Файл build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myenv.reminder"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
```

Comment: Вы используете Material стили для вашей разметки? Это стоит делать только если вы поддерживать хотите только девайсы с 5+ версией. Иначе надо использовать стили из либы поддержки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В том то и дело что проект абсолютно пустой а минимальная версия SDK стоит 4.4

Comment: Странно. Покажите build.gradle файл

Comment: Также можно попробовать сделать `clean` и `rebuid` проекту. А может у вас что-то в SDK сломалось. Попробуйте его удалить с диска и снова студией скачать

Comment: Возможно, также, что вам надо просто установить через SDK-manager всё для 19 апи

Comment: @ЮрийСПб второй раз прошу прощения, скопировал текущий файл, сейчас у меня вот такой файл как приведен выше.

Comment: В теории проблема сейчас в несовпадении `compileSdkVersion` с остальными параметрами. Попробуйте 25 поставить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так это изначально как было :( Так все работает прекрасно... Но методы в примерах которые я хочу рассмотреть становятся deprecated :(

Comment: Если `под понизить версию SDK` вы понимаете возможность запускать приложение на устройствах с ОС версии 4.4+ то так и должно быть. За возможность запускать на старых версиях отвечает только `minSdkVersion`. Остальные параметры должны быть по возможности максимальны и обязательно одинаковы

Comment: @ЮрийСПб ну вот вам пример, с которым я столкнулся. Доступ к ресурсам в зависимости от версии Android можно получить по разному. В старых версиях например getColor(), а в новых версиях данный метод deprecated. Вот из за этого я и задумался как мне понизить версию SDK.... Кстати вот туда же вопрос, в фрагментах есть метод onAttach() до 23 версии он на входе принимает активность, начиная с 23 контекст.

Comment: На всех версиях цвет нужно получать так: `ContextCompat.getColor(Context ctx, int resId)` - этот метод на разных версиях вызовет разный код и всё будет работать